# Solve ODE $xy+(3xy^2+x^2)y'=-1$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

How to solve $xy+(3xy^2+x^2)y'=-1$ ?

I have tried all the possible ways to solve an ODE but could not solve this one.

Answer (score 1):

Write equation as
$$(xy+1)dx+(3xy^2+x^2)dy=0$$
Then integrating factor is
$$\mu=\frac{1}{x}$$
and solution
$$y^3+xy+\ln x=C$$

Answer (score 0):

Beginning with @AleksasDomarkas's rearrangement and an integration factor Ansatz $\mu=x^ay^b$ viz.$$df=f_xdx+f_ydy=0,\,f_x=x^{a+1}y^{b+1}+x^ay^b,\,f_y=3x^{a+1}y^{b+2}+x^{a+2}y^b,$$for such a function $f$ to exist we require$$0=\frac{f_{xy}-f_{yx}}{x^ay^b}=(b+1)x+\frac{b}{y}-3(a+1)y^2-(a+2)x.$$Clearly $b-a-1=0,\,b=0,\,a+1=0$ has solution $a=-1,\,b=0$, so$$\mu=\frac1x,\,f_x=y+\frac1x,\,f_y=3y^2+x.$$In particular, $f:=xy+\ln|x|+y^3$ satisfies $df=0$. This $f$ is *locally constant*, allowed to have different values either side of $x=0$.